# Расстановка тире и двоеточий

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

Как бы вы проставили знаки и почему?

> В магазине на Тверской работают: Иванов и Петров; на Ленина - Кузнецов и Матвеев.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После *работают* нет необходимости ставить двоеточие, это  не однородные члены предложения. Во втором предложении ставим тире вместо пропущенного сказуемого.

Answer (score 4):

Точку с запятой ставить не стоит, хотя это и не ошибка. Запятой вполне достаточно.